# Resolve a service manually in Web API using Autofac

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

How can I resolve a service manually in a Web API project using Autofac. I have a class called Foo. Foo is instantiated by Activator.CreateInstance by another class that I have no control over, which means it would call the paramaterless constructor.

I have a few properties that need to be injected in the Foo class. Now since the calling class calls the paramaterless constructor, I need to resolve these properties manually.

```
public class Foo
{

    private IService Instance;

    public Foo()
    {
        //How do I get the per request lifetime scoped dependency resolver here
        IService = (Dependency Resolver).Resolve<IService>();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no control over the construction of this class, then the only way to do this is via a Service Locator.

Although the service locator [is considered an anti-pattern](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html), restrictions such as the one that you have force usage for such patterns.

You would have to create a static class called something like ServiceLocator. It should have some methods to register services (or it should wrap the DI container, which is what you want in this case), and other methods to locate services.

Take a look at the `Locator` class [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) for a sample locator. In your case however, you simply need a similar class that wraps the AutoFac container. So, create a static method in such Service Locator class to receive and wrap a DI container.

Regarding lifetime, you can create a special method in your service locator that allows you to resolve services using a special lifetime type (by invoking the DI container appropriately).

Having a Service Locator inside your project will create temptation to use it in situations where Dependency Injection should be used instead (which is almost all the time). Make sure that you use the Service Locator only for such cases.

Comment: In the context of Autofac in Web API 2, could you provide a sample of "creating a special method that allows you to resolve services using a special lifetime type". I do not understand this clearly.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose, if you already register the interface with the correct scope, then you don't have to do anything special in this method, just use the container to resolve the interface. How do you register your interfaces (e.g. `IService`)?

Comment: IService is registered on app startup which is a root context. When the constructor is called, the scope has the tag AutofacWebRequest, which is a per request lifetime

Comment: What I meant was when Activator.CreateInstance is called, the scope is different. It is a Per Request Lifetime Scope

Comment: Isn't that what you want? Per Request Lifetime? What happens if you use the service locator to request a service and the service locator uses the container to resolve the service? does that work?

Comment: In Autofac there seems to be no way to get the service locator in a Web Api. In an MVC project, I can do DependencyResolver.Current and it works. Is there something similar in Web API?

Comment: Why not simply call some ServiceLocator.SetContainer method after you set up the container to give it to the ServiceLocator?

Comment: When I set the Container in a place like application startup, the tag attached to the container is "root" and this does not resolve the services correctly, because the scope changes to a child called "AutofacWebRequest" when the Activator.CreateInstance is called. It gives an error stating that it cannot be resolved from a SingletonInstance i.e. the "root" container

Comment: It will be more helpful if you can provide some code to show how you are doing this. Can you update the question with such code? I would like to be able to reproduce your issue.